# Is there a way to set a variable in JavaScript equal to the property of object as a reference?

Tags: javascript

Is there any decent way to set a variable equal to some property on an object and more or less have it act as a reference to that property? I've included a snippet of code for what I'm trying to see is possible; I'm looking to see if there is something at "???" that I can get the desired `console.log` outputs. Thanks!

```
let myObject = {
    value: "test";
}

let myVar = ???;

// How do I define myVar such that...
console.log(myVar); // -> "test"
myObject.value = "new";
console.log(myVar); // -> "new"
```

Comment: For `primitives` when you create duplicates its not a reference that is created. You need to use `objects` if you want use reference.

Comment: If the property of the parent object is also an object (and not a primitive), I believe you would just set `myVar=myObject.propOb` or whatever you want to call the property.  However, in the case of primitives, I'm not sure there's a way to do what you're asking.  Typically, you would just refer to the property with dot syntax from the parent object whenever you needed the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a "decent way".

You could define a getter and setter on the global object (`window` in a browser) that provides an alternative means of getting and setting a value elsewhere:

```js
let myObject = {
    value: "test"
}
Object.defineProperty(window, "myVar", {
    configurable: true,
    get: ()=> myObject.value,
    set: value => (myObject.value=value)
});

console.log( "myObject.value %s", myObject.value);
console.log( "myVar %s", myVar);
myVar = "changed value";
console.log( "myObject.value %s", myObject.value);
console.log( "myVar %s", myVar);
```

But it does not translate well to use within a function - you can't access the function's lexical scope record to attach a setter/getter pair for use within function scope only. Using the method on the global object has little to redeem itself (= "don't do it").

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference to the object itself:

```
let myObject = {
    value: "test" // removed semicolon from here
}

let myVar = myObject;

console.log(myVar.value); // -> "test"
myObject.value = "new";
console.log(myVar.value); // -> "new"
```